# profile ImageView from several images

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, user-profile

I need to implement profile imageView for chat with some amount of members.

It should look like similar this:

[image: profile image view]

So In depending on amount of members, imageview should be splitted on appropriate parts, which should be consist of appropriate photos of each chat members.

**upd:** I found some solution (see bellow) and it works, but some images are stretched, because their real ratio is 1:1. 
How to stretch `UIImage` (with 1:1 ration) proportionally to fit rectangle size?

[image: my ex]

```
class ProfileImageHelper {

    class func collageImage (rect:CGRect, images:[UIImage]) -> UIImage {

        let maxImagesPerRow = 2
        let maxSide = rect.width / CGFloat(maxImagesPerRow)

        var index = 0
        var currentRow = 1
        var xtransform:CGFloat = 0.0
        let transformOffset:CGFloat = 1.5

        var ytransform:CGFloat = 0.0
        var smallRect:CGRect = CGRect.zero

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)//UIScreen.main.scale)

        for img in images {

            index += 1

            let x = index % maxImagesPerRow //row should change when modulus is 0

            //row changes when modulus of counter returns zero @ maxImagesPerRow
            if x == 0 {
                //last column of current row
                //xtransform += CGFloat(maxSide)
                smallRect = CGRect(x: xtransform, y: ytransform, width: maxSide - transformOffset, height: (rect.size.height / CGFloat(currentRow)) - transformOffset)

                //reset for new row
                currentRow += 1
                xtransform = 0.0
                ytransform = (maxSide * CGFloat(currentRow - 1)) + transformOffset

            } else {
                //not a new row
                if xtransform == 0 {
                    //this is first column
                    //draw rect at 0,ytransform
                    smallRect = CGRect(x: xtransform, y: ytransform, width: maxSide - transformOffset, height: (rect.size.height / CGFloat(currentRow)) - transformOffset)
                    xtransform += CGFloat(maxSide) + transformOffset
                } else {
                    //not the first column so translate x, ytransform to be reset for new rows only
                    smallRect = CGRect(x: xtransform, y: ytransform, width: maxSide - transformOffset, height: (rect.size.height / CGFloat(currentRow)) - transformOffset)
                    xtransform += CGFloat(maxSide) + transformOffset
                }
            }

            //draw in rect
            img.draw(in: smallRect)

        }

        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return outputImage!
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: draw the images on coregraphics and return as uiimage.

Comment: best way to do that use 3 image view and in that imageview draw it with breazerpath UIBezierPath for cornerradius for 3 diffent image

Comment: One UIImageView is enough. Why waste the resource with 3 ImageView for such a simple component??

Comment: the image above is just example. I need to place any amount of images in one, depending on amount members of chat.

Comment: subclass uiimageview to accept an array of uiimage, use .count of the array to decide how many slices your images will be, use coregraphics like GeneCode has suggested to piece the final image together as the image of the image view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question, using this:

```
class ProfileImageHelper {

    class func collageImage (size:CGSize, images:[UIImage]) -> UIImage {

        let maxImagesPerRow = 2
        let maxSide = size.width / CGFloat(maxImagesPerRow)

        var index = 0
        var currentRow = 1
        var xtransform:CGFloat = 0.0
        let transformOffset:CGFloat = 0.5
        var ytransform:CGFloat = 0.0
        var smallRect:CGRect = CGRect.zero

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

        for img in images {

            index += 1

            if index == 5 { break }

            let x = index % maxImagesPerRow //row should change when modulus is 0

            //row changes when modulus of counter returns zero @ maxImagesPerRow
            if x == 0 {
                //last column of current row
                //get small image for two rows column
                if Int(images.count / 2) > 1 {
                    smallRect = CGRect(x: xtransform, y: ytransform, width: maxSide - transformOffset, height: (size.height / 2) - transformOffset)
                    img.draw(in: smallRect)
                //fit image to vertical column
                } else {
                    smallRect = CGRect(x: xtransform, y: ytransform, width: maxSide - transformOffset, height: size.height)
                    if let newImage = img.cropImageByMiddle() {
                        newImage.draw(in: smallRect)
                    }
                }

                //reset for new row
                currentRow += 1
                xtransform = 0.0
                ytransform = (maxSide * CGFloat(currentRow - 1)) + transformOffset

            } else {
                //not a new row
                if xtransform == 0 {
                    //this is first column
                    //draw rect at 0,ytransform
                    if images.count == 2 {
                        smallRect = CGRect(x: xtransform, y: ytransform, width: maxSide - transformOffset, height: size.height)
                        if let newImage = img.cropImageByMiddle() {
                            newImage.draw(in: smallRect)
                        }
                    } else {
                        smallRect = CGRect(x: xtransform, y: ytransform, width: maxSide - transformOffset, height: (size.height / 2) - transformOffset)
                        img.draw(in: smallRect)
                    }
                    xtransform += CGFloat(maxSide) + transformOffset
                }
            }
        }

        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return outputImage!
    }
}
```

I crop image, getting middle part to fit it to vertical column.
For that I wrote extension for `UIImage`:

```
extension UIImage {
    func cropImageByMiddle() -> UIImage? {
        let cropRect = CGRect(x: self.size.width / 4, y: 0, width: self.size.width / 2, height: self.size.height)
        if let cgImg = self.cgImage {
            if let new = cgImg.cropping(to: cropRect) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: new)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should allow you to paste an image on top of another. You can use the x/y positions to shift the image accordingly. You can then crop the final image to a circle.

```
UIImage *backrgoundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
backrgoundImage = image1;

UIImage *foregroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
foregroundImage = image2;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backrgoundImage.size, FALSE, 0.0);
[backrgoundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, backrgoundImage.size.width, backrgoundImage.size.height)];
[foregroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(backrgoundImage.size.width/2, backrgoundImage.size.height/2, foregroundImage.size.width, foregroundImage.size.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
[imageView setImage:newImage];

// Crop the final image to a circle
CALayer *imageLayer = imageView.layer;
[imageLayer setCornerRadius:imageView.frame.size.width/2];
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
[imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
imageLayer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor clearColor]);

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Thanx I've implemented similar this, but due to uiimage doesn't have contentMode property, the images are stretched.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy code. I was't in front of my computer. Please look at my edited code. This actually works for me with no distortion. You don't need contentMode when manipulating images. Make sure you match the coordinates and size properly when you overlap the images.

Comment: Could you see my updated question. I posted my example also with stretched images. perhaps my concern would be clearly. Thanx.

Comment: The image is hard to see but it looks like the images are squeezed on the width dimension. My best guess is you are defining the height and width not respecting the provisions of the original image. The easiest way to solve it is to scale the images to the same size before overlaying them.